# Django FileField path not returning correctly

Tags: python, django, heroku

my django application involves writing many data files to the server, part of my user model class looks like this

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    course_id = models.IntegerField()
    data = models.FileField(upload_to=make_user_data_path)

def make_user_data_path(instance, filename):
    username, domain = instance.email.split('@')
    name = username + '.bin'
    return os.path.normpath(os.path.join('gameservice', 'userdata', domain, name))
```

when running on my local server i get files saved as dummy_1.bin,dummy_2.bin,dummy_3.bin...etc in app/uploads/gameservice/userdata/sgi-singapore/ , it works fine

however when i deploy to heroku it doesnt seem to be able to retrieve the data.. im getting errors like this

media root = /app/uploads/

```
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:15:28,332 base 7 140089546524416 Internal Server Error: /gameservice/f1440caf4ae6d02b26c2387d14769af9/1/user_data
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 41, in inner
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     data = user_data.data.read()
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 16, in <lambda>
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 33, in open
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/platformsite/gameservice/views.py", line 329, in user_data
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._file = self.storage.open(self.name, 'rb')
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 46, in _get_file
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._open(name, mode)
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 156, in _open
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]:     return File(open(self.path(name), mode))
2012-03-13T05:15:28+00:00 app[web.1]: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/app/uploads/gameservice/userdata/sgi-singapore.com/krislee_6547.bin'
```

when i output the saving , it seems correct ,

```
2012-03-13T05:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:42,263 views 7 140236532705024 userdata post
2012-03-13T05:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:42,267 models 7 140236532705024 path saved = gameservice/userdata/sgi-singapore.com/krislee.bin
2012-03-13T05:06:42+00:00 heroku[router]: POST pure-fire-3271.herokuapp.com/gameservice/4ed1c492de837e0cc41596378ed0fb9f/1/user_data dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=451ms status=200 bytes=5
2012-03-13T05:06:43+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:43,121 views 10 140236532705024 userdata post
2012-03-13T05:06:43+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:43,127 models 10 140236532705024 path saved = gameservice/userdata/sgi-singapore.com/krislee.bin
2012-03-13T05:06:43+00:00 heroku[router]: POST pure-fire-3271.herokuapp.com/gameservice/4ed1c492de837e0cc41596378ed0fb9f/1/user_data dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=379ms status=200 bytes=5
2012-03-13T05:06:43+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:43,826 views 8 140236532705024 userdata post
2012-03-13T05:06:43+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:43,832 models 8 140236532705024 path saved = gameservice/userdata/sgi-singapore.com/krislee.bin
2012-03-13T05:06:44+00:00 heroku[router]: POST pure-fire-3271.herokuapp.com/gameservice/4ed1c492de837e0cc41596378ed0fb9f/1/user_data dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=381ms status=200 bytes=5
2012-03-13T05:06:44+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:44,557 views 10 140236532705024 userdata post
2012-03-13T05:06:44+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:44,562 models 10 140236532705024 path saved = gameservice/userdata/sgi-singapore.com/krislee.bin
2012-03-13T05:06:44+00:00 heroku[router]: POST pure-fire-3271.herokuapp.com/gameservice/4ed1c492de837e0cc41596378ed0fb9f/1/user_data dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=363ms status=200 bytes=5
2012-03-13T05:06:45+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:45,263 views 10 140236532705024 userdata post
2012-03-13T05:06:45+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR 2012-03-13 05:06:45,268 models 10 140236532705024 path saved = gameservice/userdata/sgi-singapore.com/krislee.bin
2012-03-13T05:06:45+00:00 heroku[router]: POST pure-fire-3271.herokuapp.com/gameservice/4ed1c492de837e0cc41596378ed0fb9f/1/user_data dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=367ms status=200 bytes=5
2012-03-13T05:06:46+00:00 heroku[router]: POST pure-fire-3271.herokuapp.com/gameservice/4ed1c492de837e0cc41596378ed0fb9f/1/save_score dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=154ms status=200 bytes=14
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: file doesnt seem to be saved on the server , heroku run cat /app/uploads/gameservice/userdata/sgi-singapore.com/krislee.bin returns no such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upload files on Heroku. Your app on heroku is packaged in a git slug so it can't be modified at runtime. Use a s3 service with S3 file backend with something like django-storages http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: i want to replace my filefields with custom storages like here http://www.sourceguru.net/django-s3-storage-engine/ to minimize changes i have to do to the model. will i be on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

the files i uploaded turned out to be json files and i ended up switching them into textfields and uploading these files into the database instead of uploaded directory files. that solved my problems perfectly. if anyone is interested